# React Native file name

Tags: reactjs, native

How to remove that extra navigation bar where is saying index?
3 days trying to figure it out Can't understand why when I use just Stack screen no extra index . I just try use  index appears  .
I follow docs with just empty project same thing there name file displayed on top
Any one had same issues with Drawer ?

[image]

```
   <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
                          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                              drawerLabel: () => null, // Hide the default page name label
                              drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                                  // You can also render an icon here instead of the name
                                  <CustomDrawerScreen name={route.name} />
                              ),
                          })}

        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeContent} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
export default function HomeContent(){

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#FAFAFC"}}>
        <Stack.Screen
            options={
                {
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: COLORS.primary
                    },
                    headerShadowVisible: false,
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{
                            width: 40, height: 40, justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#ffffff", padding: 4, borderRadius: SIZES.medium,
                        }}
                                          onPress={(navigation) => {
                                              navigation.openDrawer()
                                          }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: "70%",
                                    height: "70%",
                                }}
                                source={menu}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                            />

                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ),
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{
                            width: 40, height: 40, justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#ffffff", padding: 4, borderRadius: SIZES.medium,
                        }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: "70%",
                                    height: "70%",
                                }}
                                source={notify}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ),
                    headerTitle: ""
                }
            }>
        </Stack.Screen>

        <View style={{marginBottom: 100}}>
            <Svg
                style={{position: "absolute", top: -68}}
                height="300"
                viewBox="0 0 1315 605"
                width="100%"
                dimension={"100%"}
            >
                <Path
                    fill={COLORS.primary}
                    d={'M0,160L21.8,138.7C43.6,117,87,75,131,85.3C174.5,96,218,160,262,165.3C305.5,171,349,117,393,122.7C436.4,128,480,192,524,213.3C567.3,235,611,213,655,192C698.2,171,742,149,785,144C829.1,139,873,149,916,144C960,139,1004,117,1047,138.7C1090.9,160,1135,224,1178,208C1221.8,192,1265,96,1309,48C1352.7,0,1396,0,1418,0L1440,0L1440,0L1418.2,0C1396.4,0,1353,0,1309,0C1265.5,0,1222,0,1178,0C1134.5,0,1091,0,1047,0C1003.6,0,960,0,916,0C872.7,0,829,0,785,0C741.8,0,698,0,655,0C610.9,0,567,0,524,0C480,0,436,0,393,0C349.1,0,305,0,262,0C218.2,0,175,0,131,0C87.3,0,44,0,22,0L0,0Z'}
                />
            </Svg>


            <View style={{
                width: "100%",
                position: "absolute",
                top: 60,
                left: 20,
                paddingBottom: 5
            }}>

                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: SIZES.medium,
                }}>
                    Hello David
                </Text>
                <Text style={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: SIZES.medium,
                }}>
                    Your watch list today
                </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity style={{
                    width: 40, height: 40, justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: COLORS.primary, padding: 4, borderRadius: SIZES.medium,
                    position: "absolute",

                    right: 45,
                }}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: "70%",
                            height: "70%",
                        }}
                        source={add}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>

        </View>
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            padding: SIZES.medium,
            justifyContent: "center"
        }}>

            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.primary}/>
                : error ? (
                    <Text>Something went wrong</Text>
                ) : data.length === 0 ?
                    (
                        <View style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            width: "100%",
                            padding: SIZES.medium,
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center",

                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                backgroundColor: COLORS.secondary,
                                padding: 20,
                                borderRadius: 10
                            }}>
                                <Text style={{
                                    color: COLORS.white,
                                    fontWeight: 600
                                }}

                                >No data available</Text>
                            </View>

                        </View>

                    ) : (
                        <FlatList data={data} renderItem={({item}) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                backgroundColor: COLORS.thirty,
                                borderRadius: 10,
                                margin: 5,
                                shadowColor: COLORS.primary,
                                shadowOffset: {
                                    width: 0,
                                    height: 2,
                                },
                                shadowOpacity: 0.5,
                                shadowRadius: 3.84,
                                elevation: 5,
                                padding: SIZES.small,
                            }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                                    flexDirection: "row",
                                    borderRadius: SIZES.small,
                                    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
                                    shadowColor: COLORS.white,
                                    alignItems: "center"
                                }}>
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            width: 50,
                                            height: 50,
                                            backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
                                            borderRadius: SIZES.medium,
                                            justifyContent: "center"
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Image
                                            style={{
                                                width: "70%",
                                                height: "70%",
                                            }}
                                            source={photo}
                                        />

                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{
                                        flex: 1,
                                        justifyContent: "center"
                                    }}>
                                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                                        <Text>20 y.o</Text>
                                    </View>


                                    <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                        width: 30,
                                        height: 30,
                                        justifyContent: "center",
                                        alignItems: "center",
                                        borderWidth: 1,
                                        borderColor: COLORS.primary,
                                        borderRadius: SIZES.small,
                                    }}>

                                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="check" size={24} color={COLORS.secondary}
                                                                onPress={() => {
                                                                    console.log(item.name)
                                                                }}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                </View>

                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}

                                  keyExtractor={item => item?.id}
                                  contentContainerStyle={{columnGap: SIZES.xSmall}}
                                  vertical
                        />
                    )
            }


        </View>


    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

}

Comment: it seems like its not related to drawer navogation. Please share full code so people can help you.

Comment: Code is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution very simple .

main _layout.js file in app folder wraps whole project.

To remove header

```
screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
}}
```